# How can I get my lambda to successfully call elasticbeanstalk.describeConfigurationSettings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I have a lambda that tries to access Elastic beanstalk's `describeConfigurationSettings`, but it always times out after 20 seconds which is more than enough. I assume it's because of a security issue, but I don't get a useful error message. Furthermore, I've opened up the outbound and inbound rules in my security group to allow any and all traffic (temporarily, while I debug of course), but it hasn't made a difference.

Locally, from my aws cli I'm able to complete the call, but not from my lambda.

What am I missing?

```
export const handler = async (event) => {

  const params = {
      EnvironmentName: 'example-env',
      ApplicationName: 'example-app',
  };
  
  const elasticbeanstalk = new ElasticBeanstalk();
  
  try {
    const data = await elasticbeanstalk.describeConfigurationSettings(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
    
};
```

Comment: Could it be that the IAM policy on the lambda function can not describe the EB configuration?

Comment: @MaxVisser It could be, but I'm pretty sure I updated the IAM role correctly. I see the lambda's execution role, and it has read permissions for elasticbeanstalk.describeConfigurationSettings and it still doesn't work.

Comment: For testing purposes, I would give the execution role full EB permissions and after it works to make it more secure. As you can now not completely rule out a faulty IAM execution role.
Do the logs of this Lambda function in cloudwatch tell you anything more?

Comment: @MaxVisser Yup, I did that. Full EB permissions. Still nothing. And, the Lambda Cloudwatch logs give me nothing useful. I have a couple console.log statements. before my `await` line, then it just says it timed out after 20 seconds.

Comment: not sure if you have a staging tenant in AWS but you could test giving it administrator rights and granulary restrict it. Another thing you could try is to enable cloudtrail; With it I believe you can see permission denied messages on your aws services.